# Nested for loop to output objects in QuerySet within a certain range

Tags: python, json, for-loop, django-views

I am trying to build this nested for loop and my idea is that when I go to a URL like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/search?start=1&end=3` it will show me the posts within that range.

So far this is what I have:

```
def posts_search(request):

    start = int(request.GET.get("start") or 0)
    end = int(request.GET.get("end") or (start + 9))


    posts = Post.objects.all()
    data = []
    

    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        for post in posts:
            x = post
    data.append(x)

    time.sleep(1)

    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in data
    ], safe=False)
```

The problem is when I go to that URL above, it is only outputting one post, the last post in the posts QuerySet. Regardless what start  or end value I use in the URL. When I amend the for loop to this:

```
for i in range(start, end + 1):
        for post in posts:
            data.append(post)
```

The URL above outputs the whole posts QuerySey 3 times. Please could someone help me get this for loop right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you only add `x` at the end of the `for` loop, and thus this is the last item that is assigned to `x`.

But even it this would work, it would be very inefficent, since you retrieve *all* `Post`s, and then iterate over all elements.

You should slice the queryset, so:

```
def posts_search(request):
    start = int(request.GET.get('start') or 0)
    end = int(request.GET.get('end') or start + 9)
    posts = Post.objects.all()[start:end]
    return JsonResponse(
        {'data': [post.serialize() for post in posts]}
    )
```

You can not slice a queryset with negative indices. Django will raise an `AssertionError` for this but it is better to check this, and return a valid response, in fact it might be better to use a [**`Form`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form) for this:

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    start = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    end = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, required=False)

    def clean_end(self):
        return self.cleaned_data.get('end') or cleaned_data['start'] + 9

def posts_search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        posts = Post.objects.all()[start:end]
        return JsonResponse(
            {'data': [post.serialize() for post in posts]}
        )
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'invalid numbers'})
```

You can use `form.errors` to give more detailed data.

---

> **Note**: In 2008, [Phil Haack discovered a way to obtain data from the outer JSON array](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).
> While most browser have implemented countermeasures, it is still better to use a
> JSON object as "envelope" of the data. That is why a
> [**`JsonResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
> by default does not allow something else than a `dict` as outer object. It might
> thus better to use a dictionary and keep `safe=True` on `True`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and explanation.

Comment: do not forget to check min/max ranges before `Post.objects.all()[start:end]` to avoid unexpected surprises. As minimum the numbers should be > 0

Comment: @Reishin: but `Post.objects.all()` is not a list, it is a `QuerySet`, it will thus query with `SELECT ... FROM ... OFFSET ... LIMIT ...`. You are however correc that it is better to check if `end - start` is below a certain threshold to avoid the server from processing enormous amounts of data, with a large amount of memory.

Comment: the possible issues depends on DBMS backend, but exploits still possible, which in best will result in statement exception

Comment: @Reishin: normally it is validated when subscripting that it is an `int` or `slice`, and if it is a `slice`, that both are `int`s and greater than  `0`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L294

Comment: @Reishin: Django does not allow more complicated expressions, since this is indeed a common vulnerability in ORMs that they do not (effectively) check the slices, and so it is often a way to perform SQL injection.